# Assembly REPL in Python using ctypes

Tags: python, python-3.x, assembly

I created a assembly REPL using some ctypes hacks to run the assembly code. Any suggestions on how I could improve it? I am unconcerned about some of the "obvious" security issues such as running raw assembly or using eval, since it only affects the user.

Main script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import ctypes
import re
import readline
import textwrap
import traceback

from keystone import KS_ARCH_X86, KS_MODE_64, Ks, KsError
from utils.hazmat.shellcode import run_shellcode

#ignore rbp and rsp
REG_NAMES = [
    "rax", "rbx", "rcx", "rdx", "rsi", "rdi", "r8", "r9", "r10", "r11", "r12", "r13", "r14", "r15"
]
FLAG_NAMES = {
    0: ("CF", "carry"),
    2: ("PF", "parity"),
    4: ("AF", "adjust"),
    6: ("ZF", "zero"),
    7: ("SF", "sign"),
    8: ("TF", "trap"),
    9: ("IF", "interrupt"),
    10: ("DF", "direction"),
    11: ("OF", "overflow"),
    14: ("NT", "nested_task"),
    16: ("RF", "resume"),
    17: ("VM", "virtual_x86"),
    18: ("AC", "alignment_check"),
    19: ("VIF", "virtual_interrupt"),
    20: ("VIP", "virtual_interrupt_pending"),
    21: ("ID", "cpuid")
}

def create_array(length):
    array = (ctypes.c_uint64 * length)()
    addr = ctypes.cast(array, ctypes.c_void_p).value
    return (array, addr)

class AsmRepl():
    def __init__(self, to_print=None, stack_size=128):
        if to_print is None:
            self.to_print = {"regs"}
        else:
            self.to_print = to_print
        self.stack_size = stack_size
        
        self.regs = {reg: 0 for reg in REG_NAMES}
        self.ks = Ks(KS_ARCH_X86, KS_MODE_64)
        self.libc = ctypes.CDLL("libc.so.6")
        
        self.reg_save, self.reg_save_addr = create_array(len(self.regs))
        self.stack, self.stack_addr = create_array(self.stack_size)
        self.rsp_save, self.rsp_save_addr = create_array(1)
        self.rbp_save, self.rbp_save_addr = create_array(1)
        self.flags, self.flags_addr = create_array(1)
        
        #4. save all the regs in the buffer
        #5. save flags to buffer
        #6. mov the saved rsp and rbp to rsp and rbp
        self.epilogue = self.ks.asm(
            "; ".join(
            f"mov rax, {reg}; mov [{self.reg_save_addr+i*8}], rax"
            for i, reg in enumerate(self.regs)
            ) + f";mov rax, [{self.rsp_save_addr}]; mov rsp, rax; " +
            f"mov rax, [{self.rbp_save_addr}]; mov rbp, rax; "
            f"pushfq; pop rax; mov [{self.flags_addr}], rax; ret; ",
            as_bytes=True
        )[0]
    
    def loop(self):
        while True:
            try:
                inp = input("iasm> ")
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                print()
                continue
            except EOFError:
                break
            if inp.startswith("!"):
                self.run_python(inp[1:])
            elif inp.startswith("set "):
                self.set_display(inp.split(" ")[1:])
            elif inp.startswith("reset ") or inp.startswith("clear "):
                self.clear_values(inp.split(" ")[1:])
            elif inp in ("help", "?"):
                self.print_help()
            elif inp in ("exit", "quit"):
                return
            else:
                self.run(inp)
    
    def get_libc_address(self, func):
        return ctypes.cast(self.libc[func], ctypes.c_void_p).value
    
    def run_python(self, code):
        try:
            print(
                eval(code, {
                "stack": list(self.stack),
                "flags": list(self.flags),
                **self.regs
                }, {})
            )
        except Exception:
            traceback.print_exc()
    
    def set_display(self, values):
        """add/remove values from to_print"""
        if not values:
            print("No arg provided")
            return
        if "all" in values:
            values = ["stack", "flags", "regs"]
        for val in values:
            if val.startswith("-"):
                if val[1:] in self.to_print:
                    self.to_print.remove(val[1:])
                else:
                    print(f"{val} not in to_print")
            else:
                self.to_print.add(val)
    
    def clear_values(self, values):
        if not values:
            print("No arg provided")
            return
        if "all" in values:
            values = ["stack", "regs"]
        for val in values:
            if val == "stack":
                self.stack, self.stack_addr = create_array(self.stack_size)
            elif val == "regs":
                self.regs = {reg: 0 for reg in REG_NAMES}
            else:
                print(f"Invalid value {val}")
    
    def print_help(self):
        print(
            textwrap.dedent(
            """\
        Help:
        You can provide any valid x64 assembly code to be run. For example, "mov rax, 1;".
        
        Other Commands:
        !<code> : evals python code with all registers, stack and flags as globals
        set [ stack | regs | flags_short | flags | all ] : set display of provided arg. Default is only regs. all sets stack, regs and flags.
        clear/reset [ stack | regs | all ] : clears value of provided arg
        help/? : prints this help page
        exit/quit/Ctrl-D : quits REPL"""
            )
        )
    
    def print_vals(self):
        if "stack" in self.to_print:
            print(list(self.stack))
        flags = self.flags[0]
        if "flags_short" in self.to_print:
            print(" ".join(short for i, (short, _) in FLAG_NAMES.items() if flags & (1 << i)))
        if "flags" in self.to_print:
            print(" ".join(name for i, (_, name) in FLAG_NAMES.items() if flags & (1 << i)))
        if "regs" in self.to_print:
            print(self.regs)
    
    def assemble(self, asm):
        """assemble into machine code"""
        #1. clear flags
        #2. set rsp and rbp to the stack location and save the original rsp and rbp
        #3. mov all of the saved regs to the right spot
        code = self.ks.asm(
            "push 0; popfq;"
            "mov rbx, rsp; mov rcx, rbp;" +
            f"mov rbp, {self.stack_addr + len(self.stack) * 8}; mov rsp, rbp;" +
            f"mov rax, rbx; mov [{self.rsp_save_addr}], rax;" +
            f"mov rax, rcx; mov [{self.rbp_save_addr}], rax; " +
            "; ".join(f"mov {name}, {val}" for name, val in self.regs.items()),
            as_bytes=True
        )[0]
        #4. run the user input
        # this is a separate function call to reset rip to 0
        user_code = self.ks.asm(asm, as_bytes=True)[0]
        if user_code is not None:
            code += user_code
        #5. save all the regs in the buffer
        #6. save flags to buffer
        #7. mov the saved rsp and rbp to rsp and rbp
        code += self.epilogue
        return code
    
    def run(self, asm):
        """run the assembly code"""
        #replaces <func> with libc address
        try:
            asm = re.sub(r"<(\w+)>", lambda m: str(self.get_libc_address(m.group(1))), asm)
        except IndexError as e:
            print(e)
            return
        
        try:
            code = self.assemble(asm)
        except KsError as e:
            print(e)
            return
        if "code" in self.to_print:
            print(code)
        
        run_shellcode(code)
        self.regs = {reg: val for reg, val in zip(REG_NAMES, self.reg_save)}
        self.print_vals()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    args = {"regs"}
    for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
        if arg.startswith("-") and arg[1:] in args:
            args.remove(arg[1:])
        else:
            args.add(arg)
    AsmRepl(args).loop()
```

shellcode.py:

```py
import ctypes
libc = ctypes.CDLL("libc.so.6")

#based on https://hacktracking.blogspot.com/2015/05/execute-shellcode-in-python.html
def shellcode_to_func(shellcode: bytes, func_type=None):
    if func_type is None:
        func_type = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_int)
    buf = ctypes.c_void_p(libc.valloc(len(shellcode)))  # allocate page aligned
    libc.mprotect(buf, len(shellcode), 7)  # set to rwx
    ctypes.memmove(buf, shellcode, len(shellcode))
    return ctypes.cast(buf, func_type)

def run_shellcode(shellcode: bytes):
    return shellcode_to_func(shellcode)()
```